# Print identifier on printed document

Tags: printing, microsoft-word

I have many printed documents (several thousands) and want to print unique numeric identifiers on them. The identifiers should either be generated by a special algorithm (ex. [Damm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damm_algorithm) or [Verhoeff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Verhoeff_algorithm)), or chosen from a list (I will generate them with a script using the above algorithms).

Can you please recommend a software I can use for that? Maybe, it is possible to create a custom Microsoft Word field and make it's value changing after the document is printed?

Comment: You say you want to print *unique identifiers* but the examples your give are limited to *checksums*. So, do you need the checksum capability as well, or is *any* identifier (like e.g. a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier)) ok?

Comment: @JanDoggen It was in the second sentence, actually:) I will rephrase to make it clear, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in the same question, here are the options we have found:

- A Microsoft Word document with VBA script, which updates specific text before printing. Can print to PDF too, thus avoid using Word in printing.
- A Python script which will create a PDF with IDs positioned on proper places
- A Sketch plugin which will allow to do the thing.

**UPD:** In case anyone is interested in the last case, my colleague implemented the plugin for our needs and [published it on Github](https://github.com/akolpakov/sketch-numbering-machine)